# Is it possible to know where I am sending an e-mail from?

Tags: email, networking, ip

I have a simple question.
If I send emails using my university account, from my laptopt, but through my personal home network, is it in any way possible to know where I am sending it from? For example, is it possible to get my IP for that, and my location, even if approximate?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, from some Google searches, it appears its not too difficult to get your IP from an email, [https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-trace-your-emails-back-to-the-source/#:~:text=To%20trace%20the%20IP%20address,then%20head%20to%20MX%20Toolbox](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-trace-your-emails-back-to-the-source/#:%7E:text=To%20trace%20the%20IP%20address,then%20head%20to%20MX%20Toolbox).

Then from another search, it does appear to be possible to get an approximate location from IP, [https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-lookup/#:~:text=An%20IP%20address%20lookup%20will,any%20IPv4%20or%20IPv6%20address](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-lookup/#:%7E:text=An%20IP%20address%20lookup%20will,any%20IPv4%20or%20IPv6%20address).

And to make it even easier, it appears this website will turn an IP into actual info https://www.iplocation.net/

Comment: thank you, that doesn't seem to work. I tried to use the first link to track some IPs but it only gave me the IP of the server: Microsoft for outlook emails, Google for gmail